# I received a bank check for $35000 from someone I met online. Should I deposit it?

Tags: scams

I received this with no expectations to give part of it away.  They said they would like to visit with me as soon as travel was safe.  Can not find any info when I type in the name

Comment: Did you do anything for this person, or is it literally a $35,000 "gift"?

Comment: You already know the answer. It's a scam. The check isn't real. Even if you think it "clears" it hasn't, and you'll be on the hook for any money you have spent when the bank comes collecting in a few weeks.

Comment: @Rocky That reads like an answer to me.

Comment: @Rocky Or it really will clear but it's stolen and you're unintentionally part of a money laundering plot.

Comment: @Daniel Seems unlikely here.  I don't see why they would give OP a real cheque if they don't have a good way to access the funds for themselves.  Possible, but it would basically be scammers making a pretty big gamble if that was an actual cheque.

Answer (score 10):

It is a scam, plain and simple. throw the check away and discontinue contact with the person who sent it. I know it is tempting to think there is a small chance it is real, but it isn't. It fails the smell test of why a stranger would mail you that much money for no reason and no strings attached.

Comment: Agreed. And if you don't believe this, then *tell* the sender you've deposited it (when you actually haven't) and wait for the requests for some of it to be passed on or used to "buy an iPhone for my poor sick Grandma" or whatever.

Comment: @Vicky Or take a picture next to some 70-inch TV screen and say "Thank you for my new TV"